# Calculation of CIC/FIR filter is too slow

Tags: signal-processing

I'm investigating the propeties of Cascoded Integrator Comb (CIC) filter. (for sigma-delta modulator application). I have 2 quesitons and below is what I have done:

**a)**. Any alternative method to improve my calculation speed? is my method too clumsy?

**b)**. What's the correct method to design a fast settling decimation filter, is the combination of SINC3+SINC1 in the right direciton? or any other topology? (decimation ratio `osr=128`, settling within one cycle `osr/Fs`, also with good anti-aliasing? better than SINC1?)

**1. SINC1**

The simplist one, SINC1's transfer function, it's impulse response length is `osr`

```
osr=128
normalSinc1 = (1 - z^(-osr))/ (1 - z^-1);
normalSinc1Freq = (normalSinc1/osr) /. z -> Exp[I*\[Omega]];
normalSinc1FreqPlot = 
  Plot[20*Log10[Abs[normalSinc1Freq]], {\[Omega], 0, \[Pi]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue];
normalSinc1Time := If[InverseZTransform[normalSinc1, z, n] > 0, 1, 0]
For[n = 0, normalSinc1Time > 0, n++]
normalSinc1ImpluseLength = n
```

after decimation by `osr`, alising effect of power

```
(*ideal brickwall lowpass filter, bandwith=1/osr *)
idealOSRpower = Integrate[Sqrt[0.5]^2, {f, -1/osr, 1/osr}];
(*Normal SINC1 power after decimation, Ratio=1 *)
normalSinc1FreqPower = Conjugate[normalSinc1Freq]*normalSinc1Freq;
normalSinc1FreqPowerSample = 
  Integrate[normalSinc1FreqPower, {\[Omega], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]/(2*\[Pi]);
normalSinc1Ratio = normalSinc1FreqPowerSample/idealOSRpower
```

**2. SINC3**

Then I do same thing for SINC3 filter, I found the caculation efficiency is very low, is my method is too clumsy? Any method to improve the calculation speed? Thank you!

```
normalSinc3 = (normalSinc1)^3;
normalSinc3Freq = (normalSinc1^3)/osr^3 /. z -> Exp[I*\[Omega]];
normalSinc3FreqPlot = 
  Plot[20*Log10[Abs[normalSinc3Freq]], {\[Omega], 0, \[Pi]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Black];
normalSinc3Time := If[InverseZTransform[normalSinc3, z, n] > 0, 1, 0]
For[n = 0, normalSinc3Time > 0, n++]
normalSinc3ImpluseLength = n
```

the power after decimation

```
(*Normal SINC3 power after decimation Ratio=0.55 *)
normalSinc3FreqPower = Conjugate[normalSinc3Freq]*normalSinc3Freq;
normalSinc3FreqPowerSample = 
  Integrate[
    normalSinc3FreqPower, {\[Omega], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]/(2*\[Pi]) ;
normalSinc3NBW = normalSinc3FreqPowerSample/idealOSRpower
```

**2. Fast Settling SINC3+SINC1?**

Now I understand, if my Data Ouput Rate is `Fs/osr`, settling time is: `osr/Fs` for SINC1; `(3*osr-2)/Fs` for SINC3;

Is it possible to design a filter (FIR/CIC) to achieve both fast settling (with one cycle `osr`) and good anti-aliasing? Then I try the combination of **SINC3+SINC1**. Notice! **This calculation is very time-consuming!**

```
(* sinc3(osr=r1) + sinc1(osr1=r2) *)
osr=128;
r1 = 4;
r2 = osr/r1;
fastSincN = ((1 - z^-r1)/ (1 - z^-1))^3;
fastSinc1 = (1 - z^(-r2 *r1))/ (1 - z^(-r1));
fastSinc = fastSincN*fastSinc1;
fastSincFreq = fastSinc/(r1^3)/r2 /. z -> Exp[I*\[Omega]];
fastSincFreqPlot = 
  Plot[20*Log10[Abs[fastSincFreq]], {\[Omega], 0, \[Pi]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red];
fastSincTime := If[InverseZTransform[fastSinc, z, n] > 0, 1, 0]
For[n = 0, fastSincTime > 0, n++]
fastSincImpluseLength = n
fastSincImpluseLength2 = 3*r1 - (3 - 1) + r1*(2^Log2[r2] - 1)/(2 - 1)
```

The Impluse Response Length `fastSincImpluseLength` is 134, which is close to `osr`.  The `fastSincImpluseLength2` is the relationship I summed up. Unfortunately, I found the anti-alasing capacibilty is very very poor, which is close to SINC1.**This calculation is very time-consuming!**

```
(*Fast SINC power after decimation,Ratio=0.98 *)
fastSincFreqPower = Conjugate[fastSincFreq]*fastSincFreq;
fastSincFreqPowerSample = 
  Integrate[fastSincFreqPower, {\[Omega], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]/(2*\[Pi]);
fastSincRatio = fastSincFreqPowerSample/idealOSRpower
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a faster method to calculate impulse response length. use `Serise` rather than `InverseZTransform`. No clue to improve power integral for decimation yet.

```
normalSinc3ImpluseLength = 
 Length[CoefficientList[Series[normalSinc3, {z, 0, 3*osr}], z^-1]]
```